# How can I batch substitute one font for another for all text in a collection of .EPS files?

Tags: linux, batch, fonts, eps

I have a large number (50+) of .EPS files containing data plots, which are to be imported into a LaTeX document. Most of them contain text that specifies a font I do not have available, and so compiling these files into a PDF/A1-b-compliant PDF document with all fonts embedded is not possible given this one missing font (embedding of all fonts is a hard requirement).

What I would like to do is replace all instances of this font in the .EPS files with another font I do have, e.g. Arial.

Are there any tools (preferably command line) available on Linux that would allow me to do this quickly?

A few notes:

- I have no control over the fonts in the EPS file from the plot viewer that generated them, and either way I have all these files generated already.
- From what I've found, [LaTeX doesn't have any capability of modifying the .EPS at compile time](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12941/164654), hence why I'm looking to modify the source .EPS files.

Thanks!

Comment: Might be more appropriate on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com